# Cannot add DataTable values to GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Here is my code

```
 Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable("Intervenant")
    For Each column As DataControlField In grdvIntervenants.Columns
        dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(column.HeaderText))
    Next

    Dim dr As DataRow
    For Each row As GridViewRow In grdvIntervenants.Rows
        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dr.Item(0) = row.Cells(0)
        dr.Item(1) = row.Cells(1)
        dr.Item(2) = row.Cells(2)
        dr.Item(3) = row.Cells(3)
        dr.Item(4) = row.Cells(4)
        dr.Item(5) = row.Cells(5)
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    Next

    'add new intervenant
    dr = dt.NewRow()

    dr.Item(0) = Nom
    dr.Item(1) = Prenom
    dr.Item(2) = Courriel
    dr.Item(3) = False
    dr.Item(4) = True
    dr.Item(5) = IdIntervenant

    dt.Rows.Add(dr)


    grdvIntervenants.DataSource = dt
    grdvIntervenants.DataBind()
```

I am developing in ASP.NET using VB.NET as background code. I am on vs2008 with windows 7 enterprise edition (if that info is of any help)

I have just restarted doing VB.Net and my first time using a gridview without a DataBase, so maybe I am missing something. Basically, I am trying to add a DataRow (dr) to a DataTable (dt) and then put said DataTable into a Gridview (grdvIntervenants).

My first step is to take the gridview and put all its data into a DataTable. Then i create a DataRow(dr) that I populate with variables and I add said DataRow to the DataTable. After that, I put the DataTable as the DataSource and bind the GridView.

The problem is that my GridView shows the rows but they are empty.
While debugging, I found out that this error was beside all the **DataRow.Item**:
**"In order to evaluate an indexed property, the property must be qualified and the arguments must be explicitly supplied by the user"** Seraching for it on the net, I found out it was an issue that sometimes happens to vb users but I could nto find any solution for my problem.

I did not totally understand the error, so i tried many different ways of adding the data into the DataRow but to no avail. I also tried different way of adding the column thinking the index problem might be coming from there, but again, the problem persisted. Now, something I found weird was that the Item property of my DataRow gives the quoted error, but I see the values into the ItemArray of the DataRow.

I also found out that the same error appears beside the columns property into the dataTable.

When I try to access the data from the DataSource in my rowDatabound method using the DataBinder, it gives me null results...

**So my question is: what I am missing?**

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  First, you create a datatable from data in the grid, and then you populate the grid with the datatable?

Comment: You should really show the aspx markup of your GridView. Btw, if you plan to enable paging, you should rethink your approach(f.e. query the datasource), because GridView.Rows returns only the rows of the current page.

Comment: @subt13, I create a datatable from teh data in the grid, add one row to the datatable I jsut created, then put the datatable that now has one more row into the grid, basically, adding a row to the grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is most likely that you are using the HeaderText as the column name for the data table, but this is probably not correct.

You should probably be testing to see if each column is a [BoundField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.aspx) and, if so, use the BoundField.DataField as the DataTable's column name.

For example:

```
    For Each column As DataControlField In GridView1.Columns
        If TypeOf column Is BoundField Then
            dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn(DirectCast(column, BoundField).DataField))
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: It might've been because of me using the header text
Since I did not want to lose more time on this issue, I manually created the columns into the datatable instead of creating them dynamically and now the gridview shows the results.